# Failure delivering result ResultInfo

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

There are many people who have encountered the same error on stackoverflow, but I haven't been able to find any relevant resolution in those posts. My MainActivity is starting a new activity (SecondActivity) with startActivityForResult(); SecondActivity then returns some data with onBackPressed(); and putExtra();

Extract from MainActivity.java:

```
public void addNewNote(View v){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Source", "NEW");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1); //1 is the result code

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.v("TAG", data.getStringExtra("Note"));
      if (requestCode == 1) {

         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){        
             listItems.add(data.getStringExtra("Note"));
             Log.v("TAG", data.getStringExtra("Note"));
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             listView.invalidateViews();
         }
         if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {   

         }
      }

}
```

Extract from SecondActivity.java:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed();
    if (mainTextField.getText() != null){
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("Note",mainTextField.getText());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);     
        finish();
    } else {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);        
        finish();
    }

}
```

Logcat:

[image: Logcat]

Comment: what is written at line no. 56 in MainActivity?

Comment: Log.v("TAG", data.getStringExtra("Note"));

Comment: try .toString in both case , you are getting `null`

Comment: You are getting "null", when you are fetching data with "Note" key.

Comment: chintan, unfortunately .toString didnt help. amit, do you know if the value is null in SecondActivity before it is passed

Comment: because, I'm using if (mainTextField.getText() != null){} so I don't see how it would return null

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this-

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
      if (requestCode == 1 && data != null) 
      {
         Log.v("TAG", data.getStringExtra("Note"));
         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
         {        
             listItems.add(data.getStringExtra("Note"));
             Log.v("TAG", data.getStringExtra("Note"));
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             listView.invalidateViews();
         }
         if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) 
         {   

         }
      }
}
```

Comment: alright, this stops the error from triggering, however data seems to always be null so it still isn't working, thanks though

Comment: when you are putting value in "SecondActivity" class, do it like this-
returnIntent.putExtra("Note",mainTextField.getText().toString());

Comment: yeh I just tried that, thats how it is now, still isn't working, also I know that that log statement prints out the right string from the textfield, I checked. So theres something wrong with the Intent sent back to onActivityResult

Comment: yes! finally got it working, i moved the call to the superclass, super.onBackPressed(); after everything, and it started working

Comment: In case it helps someone else along the way, my very similar problem came when I used the same onActivityResult, which updated a TextView with a new username, in 3 different Activities.  It worked in two of the activities but I got this error in the 3rd one. My problem occurred because I had forgotten to actually add the TextView in the 3rd activity which was causing a null pointer exception in the OnActivityResult, rather than the return actually being the problem. Whilst it wasn't the answer for me, the discussion here helped me find my solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with me was that I used *getIntent()*, thus getting the intent of the current activity I was on.

When I switched to *data.getStringExtra()* it worked. Amateur mistake...