# How to give cancel input to onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I call activity with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

I have to buttons "Add" and "Cancel". After user enters data and click "Add" it works fine. But I'm not sure what to add into onClickCancel because if I just put finish() I get nullPointerException cause it's expecting onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

Comment: User has option to add the data or just cancel. In that scenario it should just go back to previous activity or screen

Comment: no there are just two activities so it should go back to MainActivity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wherever you are finishing your activity just put

```
 Intent backIntent = new Intent();
 setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, backIntent);
 finish();
```

and in `OnActivityResult()` you can do (First statement)

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just judge the requestCode and data in the method *onActivityResult*, if requestCode not match or data is null, then do noting

Comment: If I put setResult(0, intent) I get java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity

Comment: This Exception isn't the real reason, it because of NullPointException occur in onActivityResult. This maybe helpful : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782619/failure-delivering-result-resultinfo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782619/failure-delivering-result-resultinfo)

Comment: Next time you may put detail exception stack on here, it can help more exactly found problem : )

Answer (score 0):

The onClick() event for "Cancel" button can have finish() method of activity.

```
@override
public void onClick(View v){
finish();
}
```

But the activity, where you send the intent to DetailsActivity.class you call it as

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

So, you should override **onActivityResult()** method of the activity, in the same activity and should handle request code and result code. The cases are null or not null and the result code will be an integer number. Refer the documentation for this.

The another solution is, if you are not expecting any data from DetailsActivity, you can simply call

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
startActivity(intent, 1);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this:

```
public void cancelButton(View view) {

    startActivity(new Intent(MyCurrentActivity.this, TheClassIWantToReturnToActivity.class));
}
```

In the xml.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="cancelButton" 
    android:text="CANCEL" />
```

It is separate for the OnActivityResult  as it is an onclick action, independent of posting any data, or whatever you are doing with your send button.